# Multiple Controls onto a single control c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls

Is there any way to make a Control like a `Panel`, and inserting several other components like a `Label` in it?

I've made a custom control, and added some controls from the toolbox into it's [Designer], though those items aren't visible when inserting the custom control into the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Basically

- make a new `custom control`
- Then (into the designer of the freshly made custom control)  add some
  elements from the toolbox, like a label. They will just appear as boxes.
- Finally go to the code of the custom control, and add
  `this.Controls.Add(label1)`.   I found this into the designer of the
  form to insert a control into another one.

MultiControl.cs:

```
public partial class MultiControl : Panel
{
    public MultiControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
    }
 }
```

and here the designer code:

```
partial class MultiControl
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your usercontrol's and main project both belong to the same solution, then the UserControl will appear at the top of the Designer Toolbox **automatically**.

However if your user control is in another solution and your main project has a reference to the dll, then you need to add the control to the Toolbox **manually**.

With the designer open on your main project, right click the Toolbox and choose **Choose Items...**.

From .NET Framework Components, click Browse and select your user control's DLL.

Click OK.

Click OK.

All the public controls in your assembly should now be visible in the Toolbox.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Though actually I try to make a control like a `Panel` and put more elements in the Panel. So that this one control would become a panel with several labels in it as one assembly. Though they are all inside the same solution.

Comment: @Dextroy Whether the control is a composite control (such as yours) or something purely rendered, the procedure is the same